# Windows 8 taskbar buttons appearance for selected window

Tags: windows-8

How do I setup windows 8 so that the button of the selected (active) window appear "pressed in" in the taskbar?

eg (for windows vista) : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows-vista/the-taskbar-overview

Comment: Even Win7 only highlights the active window's taskbar button a little, and many people have complained that it's hard to distinguish from an inactive window's button. Most likely you'll have to use a 3rd party theming utility and some theme which makes the difference between active and inactive buttons more apparent.

Comment: Yes. That sucks. In windows 7, I used to set the windows classic theme for this particular reason. Because usually I have several instances of the same program running (eg visual studio) and in windows 8 it's hard to tell which visual is "active"